# why factor() does not take out the levels of a factor that have no observations in R

Tags: r, r-factor

Anybody could tell me how is this possible?

```
> levels(x$Species)
 [1] "alisterus amboinensis"        "amazona viridigenalis"        "aprosmictus erythropterus"   
 [4] "ara macao"                    "aratinga pertinax"            "bolbopsittacus lunulatus"    
 [7] "brotogeris jugularis"         "cacatua sulphurea"            "charmosyna papou"            
[10] "coracopsis vasa"              "cyanoliseus patagonus"        "cyanoramphus auriceps"       
[13] "cyclopsitta diophthalma"      "deroptyus accipitrinus"       "diopsittaca nobilis"         
[16] "eclectus roratus"             "enicognathus leptorhynchus"   "eos reticulata"              
[19] "forpus passerinus"            "geoffroyus heteroclitus"      "guaruba guarouba"            
[22] "hapalopsittaca amazonina"     "leptosittaca branickii"       "loriculus galgulus"          
[25] "lorius albidinuchus"          "melopsittacus undulatus"      "micropsitta finschii"        
[28] "myiopsitta monachus"          "nandayus nenday"              "nannopsittaca panychlora"    
[31] "neopsephotus bourkii"         "neopsittacus musschenbroekii" "nestor notabilis"            
[34] "northiella haematogaster"     "orthopsittaca manilata"       "phigys solitarius"           
[37] "pionites melanocephala"       "pionopsitta caica"            "pionus menstruus"            
[40] "platycercus adscitus"         "poicephalus robustus"         "polytelis alexandrae"        
[43] "prioniturus luconensis"       "prosopeia tabuensis"          "pseudeos fuscata"            
[46] "psittacula columboides"       "psittaculirostris edwardsii"  "psittacus erithacus"         
[49] "psittrichas fulgidus"         "purpureicephalus spurius"     "pyrrhura picta"              
[52] "rhynchopsitta pachyrhyncha"   "tanygnathus lucionensis"      "touit batavica"              
[55] "vini australis"              
> x[x$species=="vini australis",]
[1] Species   Longitude Latitude 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> x$Species=factor(x$Species)
> levels(x$Species)
 [1] "alisterus amboinensis"        "amazona viridigenalis"        "aprosmictus erythropterus"   
 [4] "ara macao"                    "aratinga pertinax"            "bolbopsittacus lunulatus"    
 [7] "brotogeris jugularis"         "cacatua sulphurea"            "charmosyna papou"            
[10] "coracopsis vasa"              "cyanoliseus patagonus"        "cyanoramphus auriceps"       
[13] "cyclopsitta diophthalma"      "deroptyus accipitrinus"       "diopsittaca nobilis"         
[16] "eclectus roratus"             "enicognathus leptorhynchus"   "eos reticulata"              
[19] "forpus passerinus"            "geoffroyus heteroclitus"      "guaruba guarouba"            
[22] "hapalopsittaca amazonina"     "leptosittaca branickii"       "loriculus galgulus"          
[25] "lorius albidinuchus"          "melopsittacus undulatus"      "micropsitta finschii"        
[28] "myiopsitta monachus"          "nandayus nenday"              "nannopsittaca panychlora"    
[31] "neopsephotus bourkii"         "neopsittacus musschenbroekii" "nestor notabilis"            
[34] "northiella haematogaster"     "orthopsittaca manilata"       "phigys solitarius"           
[37] "pionites melanocephala"       "pionopsitta caica"            "pionus menstruus"            
[40] "platycercus adscitus"         "poicephalus robustus"         "polytelis alexandrae"        
[43] "prioniturus luconensis"       "prosopeia tabuensis"          "pseudeos fuscata"            
[46] "psittacula columboides"       "psittaculirostris edwardsii"  "psittacus erithacus"         
[49] "psittrichas fulgidus"         "purpureicephalus spurius"     "pyrrhura picta"              
[52] "rhynchopsitta pachyrhyncha"   "tanygnathus lucionensis"      "touit batavica"              
[55] "vini australis"              
> x[x$species=="vini australis",]
[1] Species   Longitude Latitude 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: Note that R is case sensitive.  `x$species` is not the same as `x$Species`

Comment: ops, Dason, you are perfectly right..its a shame this continues to be an issue after my long time using this program..:/

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the function `droplevels`.  It removes unused levels from a factor.

Levels aren't dropped by default, as you have seen.  You might want to know that there are values for which there are no observations.

Here's an example:

```
(x <- factor(LETTERS))
##  [1] A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
## Levels: A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

Now take a subset:

```
(y <- x[10:15])
## [1] J K L M N O
## Levels: A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

And dropping the levels results in :

```
(z <- droplevels(y))
## [1] J K L M N O
## Levels: J K L M N O
```

Unused levels are no longer present.  Be careful if you're using the numeric value of a factor, as `droplevels` changes the representation:

```
as.numeric(y)
## [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15

as.numeric(z)
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: thanks Matthew, but it did not work: x$Species=droplevels(x$Species)
levels(x$Species) gives me the same list as above

Comment: In that case, you *do* have observations with those factor levels.